# Все способы нажать на кнопку wdio/js

Tags: javascript, mocha

Столкнулся с ситуацией, когда кое какие кнопки или же поля для ввода данных попросту не хотят нажиматься с помощью .click() или добавлять значение с помощью addValue() / setValue(). Какие есть еще способы выполнить эти действия ?

Comment: попросту ничего не бывает. а по поводу `click`, есть похожее событие `pointerdown`

Comment: @highpassion ну хорошо, а как тогда объяснить ситуацию, в которой мы имеем кнопку Log In, которая имеет айди селектор, пишу .click(), а этот шаг попросту игнорируется

Comment: код скиньте или сайт, причина всегда есть, где вызываете метод тоже скажите

Comment: Возможно, на момент выполнения функции .click() страница с кнопкой ещё не загрузилась.